# Print text between delimiters using sed

Tags: printing, sed

Suppose I have `op(abc)asdfasdf` and I need `sed` to print `abc` between the brackets. What would work for me? (Note: I only want the text between first pair of delimiters on a line, and nothing if a particular line of input does not have a pair of brackets.)

Comment: The duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875129/extract-text-between-two-given-different-delimiters-in-a-given-text-in-bash has a number of non-`sed` solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/^[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*/s//\1/p'
```

The pattern looks for lines that start with a list of zero or more characters that are not open parentheses, then an open parenthesis; then start remembering a list of zero or more characters that are not close parentheses, then a close parenthesis, followed by anything.  Replace the input with the list you remembered and print it.  The `-n` means 'do not print by default' - any lines of input without the parentheses will not be printed.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ echo 'op(abc)asdfasdf' | sed 's|[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*|\1|'
abc
```

Comment: awesome it works, could you please explain what the syntax mean so I can play around with it to solve similar problems?

Comment: @mark see answer from @jonathan-leffler above where he fully describe how it works. One difference is that I not use -n option (but probably should because when string not match, my one-liner will print original string).

Comment: @Mark: the explanation is essentially the same as in my answer; the solution is essentially the same as mine.  One difference is that php-coder uses '|' where I use '/'.  Otherwise, his solution prints lines that don't contain a matched pair of parentheses, whereas mine deletes lines that don't match - a difference of interpretation of your question.  On the sample input, both solutions produce the same output.