# Print text between ( )  sed

Tags: printing, sed

This is an extension of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972622/print-text-between-delimiters-using-sed/).  In that question, I needed to retrieve the text between parentheses where all the text was on a single line.  Now I have this case:

```
(aop)
(abc
d)
```

This time, the open parenthesis can be on one line and the close parenthesis on another line, so:

```
(abc
d)
```

also counts as text between the delimiters '`( )`' and I need to print it as

```
abc
d
```

EDIT:
In response to possible confusions of my question, let me clarify a little. Basically, I need to print text between delimiters which could span multiple lines.

for example I have this text in my file:

```
randomtext(1234
567) randomtext
randomtext(abc)randomtext
```

Now I want Sed to pick out text between the delimiter "(" and ")". So the output would be:

```
1234
567
abc
```

Notice that the left and right brackets are not on the same line but they still count as a delimiter for 1234 567, so I need to print that part of the text. (note, I only want the text between the first pair of delimiters).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can hardly understand your question.

Comment: @Rahul basically I need to do multi-line printing with Sed to print text between delimiters.

Comment: I have edited the question for better clarity.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the edit! Edit: Also, how did you get the text to appear on a gray background?

Comment: NP - though I see I should have changed 'for example' to 'For example'...You get 'code' to look like code by typing it in and then selecting it, and pressing the '{}' icon above the text editing box; that indents it four spaces, which indicates code, and uses constant-width font, and a gray background.  It also stops the text wrapping.  There's a link button too - you highlight the text (eg 'question') and click; then you can type (or, more usually, paste) the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! another tricky sed puzzle :)

I believe this code will work for your problem:

```
sed -n '/(/,/)/{:a; $!N; /)/!{$!ba}; s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p}' file
```

#### OUTPUT

For the provided input it produced:

```
1234
567
abc
```

**Explanation:**

- `-n` suppresses the regular sed output
- `/(/,/)/` is for range selection between `(` and `)`
- `:a` is for marking a label a
- `$!N` means append the next line of input into the current pattern space
- `/)/!` means do some actions if `)` is not matched in current pattern space
- `/)/!${!ba}` means go to label `a` if `)` is not matched in current pattern space
- `s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/` means replace content between `(` and `)` by just the content thus stripping out parenthesis
- `\1` is for back reference of group 1 i.e. text between `\(` and `\)`
- `p` is for printing the replaced content

Comment: I bow before your sed mastery.  Your sed-fu is strong!

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the great answer and explanation! However, I am having trouble running this on slackware 13.37. The output is: sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown command: `$'

Comment: @mark: can you try this one: `sed -n '/(/,/)/{$!N; /)/!{$!N;}; s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p;}' file` I don't have access to slackware but tested it on Mac & Linux.

Comment: @anubhava I have tried the both code again and I am getting N: event not found. Could it be I am using a different standard of SED? (note I have tried it on both slackware and ubuntu.)

Comment: on Ubuntu is should be fine if it is current version of Ubuntu. In fact I built above command on my Ubuntu itself :)

Comment: I am using ubuntu 9.10. The output is still linux006:~> sed -n '/(/,/)/{:a; $!N; /)/!{$!ba}; s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p}' input1.txt
N: Event not found

Comment: Meanwhile can you pls try this command: `sed -n '/(/,/)/{:a;$!N;/)/!{$!ba;};s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p;}' file` (removed extra space)

Comment: Yeah I have just tried it, it still seems to be giving me the same output. :( sorry to bother you so much.

Comment: @anubhava I have just install a brand new up to date version of linux and the code is working fine now but there is one minor problem, I have updated the sample input and output in the question I would like to tweak it to fit the case.

Comment: Glad that at least existing answer worked for you for your original problem. But your updated problem seems to be lot more different that the original one. I would suggest posting that update section as a new question pointing this one as reference. Since this being the old problem wouldn't get many people's attention. I will also have to think from fresh point how to solve the new problem now :)

Comment: Thanks I have posted the new question.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/) has the answer. I am paraphrasing to match your need:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/;p}' < your_input
```

Comment: it seems to work, however it only outputs the text for the last pair of delimiters. Any idea on how to tweak it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given didn't work for my case. What worked for me was:

```
cat file | tr -d '\n'
```

^^^
this puts the whole file in a single line by deleting line breaks.

and then I further piped it into the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1467135/sed-match-a-string-between-two-different-consecutive-matches-on-all-occurrencie). (note: instead of brackets, OPEN and CLOSE are used in that question)