# using sed to print between two patterns

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

So I've found a great deal on [deleting the text between two patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071901/removing-lines-between-two-patterns-not-inclusive-with-sed) and on [printing the text between two delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023615/using-sed-to-print-between-delimiters) but I haven't found anything on printing the text between two patterns using bash functions.

If I have:

```
"Alas poor Yorik, I knew him well"
```

and I want to print everything between the patterns "poor" and "well" (exclusive) I would get:

```
" Yorik, I knew him "
```

How could I achieve this using something like sed or awk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ echo "Alas poor Yorik, I knew him well" | sed -e 's/^.*poor //g;s/ well.*$//g'
Yorik, I knew him
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ echo "Alas poor Yorik, I knew him well" | awk '{sub(/.*poor /,"");sub(/ well.*/,"");print;}'
Yorik, I knew him
```

Usage with file input:

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ echo "Alas poor Yorik, I knew him well" > infile
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat infile 
Alas poor Yorik, I knew him well
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat infile | sed -e 's/^.*poor //g;s/ well.*$//g'
Yorik, I knew him
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ sed -e 's/^.*poor //g;s/ well.*$//g' < infile
Yorik, I knew him
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat infile | awk '{sub(/.*poor /,"");sub(/ well.*/,"");print;}'
Yorik, I knew him
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ awk '{sub(/.*poor /,"");sub(/ well.*/,"");print;}' < infile 
Yorik, I knew him
```

Comment: Actually it's matter of regular expression you use, in some cases bracket expression (.*poor)(.*)(well.*) or similar, and backreference - /2 in this example, would be more readable, anyway the trick is to use regex definition(s).

Comment: updated with file input usage

Comment: I recommend you this book  
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/index.htm as well as this one http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/index.htm