# sed/awk/bash to replace text between two strings with external file contents

Tags: bash, replace, sed, awk

I'm looking to write a script/command, that'll take inputFile1, look for a specific start and end string in it, and replace all the text in between them
with the full contents of inputFile2.

Ideally, but not mandatory, this should work without a need to escape special characters, so I can put the strings in variables that get called by the script (that way I could easily reuse it multiple times).

As an example, I have file *inputYes.txt* with contents:

```
DummyOne
Start
That
What
Yes
End
DummyTwo
```

And *inputNo.txt* with contents:

```
This
Why
Not
```

And I want the script to search *inputYes.txt* for the strings *Start* and *End*, and replace all the text in between with the contents of *inputNo.txt*, and write to the file.

So after running it, *inputYes.txt* should read

```
DummyOne
Start
This
Why
Not
End
DummyTwo
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of a question I already answered.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443122/using-sed-to-print-between-two-patterns/12443133#12443133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/end_string/rinputFile2
/start_string/,/end_string/d' inputFile1
```

Comment: I can't exactly tell what this is doing, but I can tell it's not working, it seems to simply be echoing the contents of inputFile1. And I need it to write to the file, not just print on the terminal. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: Any text between the lines which match `start_string` and `end_string` should be replaced with the contents of `inputFile2`.  Redirecting the output to a file is trivial.

Comment: It's not doing anything on my system. I'm running OSX, perhaps `sed` is different?

Comment: According to my post edit, I'm running `sed '/End/rinputNo.txt/Start/,/End/d' inputYes.txt`, and it's simply printing the contents of _inputYes.txt_.

Comment: Newlines are significant.  The command must have a literal newline after the filename.  Your command is looking for a file named `inputNo.txt/Start/,/End/d`

Comment: I thought the line had been truncated, didn't realize it was on purpose, thank you very much, it works. Extra tip, can I tell it to add a newline at the end of the substitution?

Comment: The easiest way would be to add an extra newline to the end of `inputFile1`.