# Find and append to Text Between Two Strings or Words using sed or awk

Tags: regex, awk, replace, sed

I am looking for a `sed` in which I can recognize all of the text in between two indicators and then replace it with a place holder.

For instance, the 1st indicator is a list of words

```
(no|noone|haven't)
```

and the 2nd indicator is a list of punctuation
Code:

```
(.|,|!)
```

From an input text such as

> "Noone understands the plot. There is no storyline. I haven't
>   recommended this movie to my friends! Did you understand it?"

The desired result would be.

> "Noone understands_AFFIX me_AFFIX. There is no storyline_AFFIX. I
>   haven't recommended_AFFIX this_AFFIX movie_AFFIX to_AFFIX my_AFFIX
>   friends_AFFIX! Did you understand it?"

I know that there is the following `sed`:

```
sed -n '/WORD1/,/WORD2/p' /path/to/file
```

which recognizes the content between two indicators. I have also found a lot of great information and resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443122/using-sed-to-print-between-two-patterns). However, I still cannot find a way to append the affix to each token of text that occurs between the two indicators.

I have also considered to use `awk`,  such as

```
awk '{sub(/.*indic1 /,"");sub(/ indic2.*/,"");print;}' < infile
```

yet still, it does not allow me to append the affix.

Does anyone have a suggestion to do so, either with `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: A. The sed syntax you're relying on, relies on lines to delimit the range, so it won't work on text that is in the same line. B. You'll do better searching 1 word at a time in `awk` and managing the output there. C. your example seem inconsistent. The application of your "rule" to `Noone understands the plot` produced `Noone understands_AFFIX me_AFFIX.` where as `There is no storyline.` produced `There is no storyline_AFFIX` . How did `AFFIX` get inserted 2x in the first and only 1x in the 2nd?  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little more compact `awk`

```
$ awk              'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" ";s="_AFFIX"} 
                 /[.,!]$/{f=0; $0=gensub(/(.)$/,"s\\1","g")}  
                        f{$0=$0s} 
    /Noone|no|haven'\''t/{f=1}1' story
```

> Noone understands_AFFIX the_AFFIX plot_AFFIX. There is no storyline_AFFIX. I haven't recommended_AFFIX this_AFFIX movie_AFFIX to_AFFIX my_AFFIX friends_AFFIX! Did you understand it?

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/(?:no(?:one)?|haven'\''t)\s*\K([^.,!]+)/
            join " ", map "${_}_AFFIX", split " ", $1/egi
         ' infile > outfile
```

- `\K` matches what's on its left, but excludes it from the replacement. In this case, it verifies the 1st indicator. (`\K` needs Perl 5.10+.)
- `/e` evaluates the replacement part as code. In this case, the code splits `$1` on whitespace, map adds `_AFFIX` to each of the members, and `join` joins them back into a string.

Comment: I didn't even think of using `perl` for this problem. Just one question. In regards to the indicators, are they searching for real words (i.e. -w) or just if they find the part of the indicator word in a word?

Comment: @owwoow14: As written here, they match as a substring, too. You can add word boundaries `\b` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one verbose awk command for the same:

```
s="Noone understands the plot. There is no storyline. I haven't recommended this movie to my friends! Did you understand it?"

awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v kw="no|noone|haven't" -v pct='\\.|,|!' '{
   a=0
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ($(i-1) ~ "\\y" kw "\\y")
         a=1
      if (a && $i ~ pct "$") {
         p = substr($i, length($i), 1)
         $i = substr($i, 1, length($i)-1)
      }
      if (a)
         $i=$i "_AFFIX" p
      if(p) {
         p=""
         a=0
      }
   }
} 1'
```

**Output:**

> `Noone understands_AFFIX the_AFFIX plot_AFFIX. There is no storyline_AFFIX. I haven't recommended_AFFIX this_AFFIX movie_AFFIX to_AFFIX my_AFFIX friends_AFFIX! Did you understand it?`