# How to extract text between two words in unix?

Tags: unix, sed, pattern-matching

I 
am 
using 
basic 
sed 
expression :-

```
sed -n "am/,/sed/p"
```

to get the text between "am" and "sed" 
which will output "am \n using \n basic \n sed".
But my real problem is if the string would be :-

I 
am 
using 
basic 
grep 
expression.

I applied the above sed in this sentence
then it gave "am \n using \n basic \n grep \n expression"
which it should not give it. How to discard the 
output if there would be no matching?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's with all the '`\n`' characters you so carefully added in your edit?  They simply make your question illegible - but I can't quite work out what they're for, so it is hard to say whether simply deleting them is sensible...

Comment: I am a newbie, will try to make it eligible. You can always tell the tricks to make the question more readable. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Amitesh: it's fine to be a newbie - we all were once.  I'm just confused about what you're trying to achieve with the '`\n`' notation.  It looks as if you are thinking "if you take this question as input, ...", but I'm not sure.  Otherwise, I'd simply delete all occurrences of '`\n`', not least because the sequence has a meaning in `sed` scripts which I don't think you are after.

Comment: See [Print text between delimiters on multiple lines using sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972908/print-text-between-delimiters-on-multiple-lines-using-sed).  That was dealing with text between '(' and ')', but there isn't all that much difference between it and what you're after.  The main big difference is that the ')' is a single character, so a negated character class '`[^)]*`' handles 'skip over the uninteresting stuff.  It isn't quite so simple with multi-character delimiters.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I meant to make the picture more clearer as there was newline between the words and it has importance in sed.

Comment: I admire your creativity; I am not sure that I find it easy to read, in either form.  Sorry to rain on your parade, but straight-forward English is easiest for all to handle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command in the question (`sed -n "/am/,/sed/p"`, note the added slash) means:

- Find a *line* containing the string `am`
- and print (`p`) until a line containing `sed` occurs

Therefore it prints:

```
I am using basic grep expression
```

because it contains `am`. If you would add some more lines they will be printed, too, until a line containing `sed` occurs.

E.g.:

```
echo -e 'I am using basic grep expression.\nOne more line\nOne with sed\nOne without' | sed -n "/am/,/sed/p"
```

results in:

```
I am using basic grep expression.
One more line
One with sed
```

I think - what you want to do is something like that:

```
sed -n "s/.*\(am.*sed\).*/\1/p"
```

Example:

```
echo 'I am using basic grep expression.' | sed -n "s/.*\(am.*sed\).*/\1/p"

echo 'I am using basic sed expression.' | sed -n "s/.*\(am.*sed\).*/\1/p"
sed -n "s/.*\(am.*sed\).*/\1/p"
```

Comment: I have to be more detailed. Actually, there are multiple lines and we want to extract some lines between two words. If there would be a match of the "start word" and "stop word" then the above expression would be ok. But if there would be only the "start word" and no "stop word", it would output all the lines beyond the "start word". I hope you would get it know. Thanks.

Comment: @amitesh: OK - in that case anubhava's answer is what you need.

Comment: is there way to get string between 2 words(it should not include itself), i.e am and sed should not be included in itself

Comment: also, your answer is giving only first match(or may be last match), but what if i want all the matches

Answer (score 3):

You have to use slightly different sed command like:

```
sed -n '/am/{:a; /am/x; $!N; /sed/!{$!ba;}; /sed/{s/\n/ /gp;}}' file
```

To print ONLY lines that contain text `am` and `sed` spanned across multiple lines.

Comment: The words are in different lines. Pls review the question.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your input file in your question?

Comment: The first line of the question is the input file. \n represents newline.

Answer (score 1):

When Using SED this can work but it's quite an overwhelming syntax...
if you need to **crop part of a multi-line (\n) text**, you might want to try a simpler way using **grep**:

```
cat multi_line.txt | grep -oP '(?s)(?<=START phrase).*(?=END phrase)'
```

For example, I find this as the easiest way to grab **perforce changelist description** (without rest of CL info):

```
p4 describe {CL NUMBER} | grep -oP '(?s).*(?=Affected files)'
```

Note, you can play with the <= and >=   to include or not include, the starting/ending phrases in the output.

Comment: `grep -P` is a non-standard extension which isn't generally portable, though it works on GNU `grep` and possibly some other versions. (macOS `grep` used to have this option, but removed it.)