# remove anything after this string END_PAGEREFS

Tags: regex

i have large numbers of text files and i am in problem that i want to remove anything after this string END_PAGEREFS   and remove anything before BEGIN_PAGEREFS as i want in between them

thanks

Comment: It would be nice to know what language...

Comment: really thanks for fast response i am bignner in regex i use powergrip software http://www.regular-expressions.info/ if you can help me

or guide me with complete solve for my problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract text between two words in unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127786/how-to-extract-text-between-two-words-in-unix)

Answer (score 0):

sed can be used for this:

```
sed -i -n '/BEGIN_PAGEREFS/,/END_PAGEREFS/p' yourfile
```

this command can be inserted in a loop to process all your files