# Extract text between two given different delimiters in a given text in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a line of text which looks like `hh^ay-pau+h@ow`, I want to extract the text between `-` and `+` which in this case is `pau`. This should be done in bash. Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT: I want to extract the text between the first occurence of the tokens
PS: My google search didn't take me anywhere. I apologize if this question is already asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this in pure `bash`, is by using parameter expansions in bash

```
$ a=hh^ay-pau+h@ow
$ b=${a%%+*}
$ c=${b#*-}
$ echo $c
pau
```

b: remove everything including and behind the first `+` occurence
c: remove everything excluding and before the first `-` ocurrence

More info about [substring removing in bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
grep -Po "(?<=\-).*?(?=\+)"
```

For example,

```
echo "hh^ay-pau+h@ow" | grep -Po "(?<=\-).*?(?=\+)"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one occurence of `-` and `+` you can use cut:

```
 $ echo "hh^ay-pau+h@ow" | cut -d "-" -f 2 | cut -d "+" -f 1
 pau
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming one occurence of `+` and `-`, you can stick to `bash`

```
IFS=+- read -r _ x _ <<<'hh^ay-pau+h@ow'             
echo $x
pau
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're guarenteed to only have one `-` and one `+` .

```
 % echo "hh^ay-pau+h@ow" | sed -e 's/.*-//' -e 's/+.*//'
 pau
```

Comment: could you please explain the sed command, actually I wanted to extract the text between the first occurence of "-" and "+". There are multiple occurences of both tokens

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "hh^ay-pau+h@ow" | awk -F'-' '{print $2}' |awk -F'+' '{print $1}'
```