# selecting the text between brackets () and manipulating it

Tags: regex, awk, sed, brackets

From the Question, [Print text between delimiters using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972622/print-text-between-delimiters-using-sed/)
I am able to get the text between brackets. But when i want to modify, I am finding difficulty. Can somebody, please help me?

**simple case:**

input:

```
mutex_lock(rdlock);
```

output:
Here, I want to print the name text between () before and after as below.

```
printf("locking rdlock");mutex_lock(rdlock);printf("locked rdlock");
```

**complicated case:**

input:

```
mutex_lock(&in->bq[CPORT].lock);
```

output:

```
printf("locking &in->bq[CPORT].lock");mutex_lock(&in->bq[CPORT].lock);printf("locked &in->bq[CPORT].lock");
```

Thanks many in advance.

Comment: Can input also contain brackets like: `mutex_lock( obj->foo() );`?

Comment: no. No nested brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
sed  's/\(.*(\(.*\));\)/printf ("locking \2");\n\1\nprintf("locked \2");/g'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo  "mutex_lock(rdlock);" | sed  's/\(.*(\(.*\));\)/printf ("locking \2");\n\1\nprintf("locking \2");/g'
printf ("locked rdlock");
mutex_lock(rdlock);
printf("locking rdlock");
```

and

```
$ echo  "mutex_lock(&in->bq[CPORT].lock);" | sed  's/\(.*(\(.*\));\)/printf ("locking \2");\n\1\nprintf ("locking \2");/g'
printf ("locking &in->bq[CPORT].lock");
mutex_lock(&in->bq[CPORT].lock);
printf ("locking &in->bq[CPORT].lock");
```

---

**EDIT**

To be exact

```
sed  's/\(mutex_lock(\(.*\));\)/printf ("locking \2");\n\1\nprintf ("locking \2");/g'
```

**Test**

```
echo  "mutex_lock(&in->bq[CPORT].lock);" | sed  's/\(mutex_lock(\(.*\));\)/printf ("locking \2");\n\1\nprintf ("locking \2");/g'
printf ("locking &in->bq[CPORT].lock");
mutex_lock(&in->bq[CPORT].lock);
printf ("locking &in->bq[CPORT].lock");
```

---

For better safety, you can write

```
sed -r  's/(mutex_lock\(([^)]*)\);)/printf ("locking \2);\n\1\nprintf ("locking \2");/g'
```

- `[^)]` negatec character class. Would match anything other than `)`

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. Works as expected.

Comment: @ nu11p01n73R, To be very exact,  
sed   's/mutex_lock\(.*(\(.*\));\)/dprintk("locking \2");mutex_lock(\2);dprintk("locked \2");/g'

Comment: @BalamuruganA You need not have a `.*` after the `mutex_lock`. I have edited my answer to include that *very exact* part ;)

Comment: @ nu11p01n73R, Thanks. Accepting answer. small correction, " is missing at the end in first line.

Comment: @BalamuruganA Oops. Corrected in answer.

Comment: You should probably change `mutex_lock(\(.*\))` to `mutex_lock(\([^)]*\))` just in case there can be something else with parens later on the line. +1 though.

Comment: @EdMorton That is a pretty good catch. Added in the answer. Thank you